# how to display the sorted list in listview after user presses the sort button?

Tags: android, listview

I am making an Simple Android App to test the sorting capability and then use it on my main project that I will be making.

I want to know that suppose I display a list of items to the user with the help of custom objects and custom ArrayAdapter in the listview and there I want to place a sorting button that will sort the list during runtime according to the choice of the user (ex: alphabetically, according to ratings,etc.).

How to display the new list to the user after sorting.

Should I again use the setAdapter method or is there any other way?

Comment: Use `notifyDatasetChanged()` maybe?

Comment: after sorting your list simply call `notifyDatasetChanged()` method on you adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in your adapter your list will be redrawn in the right order in the screen. :) So after you order you list, call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: So, after I sort the list after handling the event then call the adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() method?

Comment: Yes, this way the adapter will redraw the views using the new sorted list. Note that you'll need to sort the list you've passed to the adapter previously.

Answer (score 1):

When you **click** **Sort Button** , **perfom sorting on the list** , *and in the next line write*

```
yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

*it will update your list with the* **updated(sorted) Data**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sort your source data base on the choice of the user (ex: alphabetically, according to ratings,etc.)
Ex:

```
List<String> mData; // your source data
// sort your data ascending order
Collections.sort(mData);
// use your adapter to update your ListView
mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right, create new adapter is a bad practice and waste of memory as well. Tell me if it's work ok?